# Prime numbers in binary.

Tags: prime-numbers

So I am currently writing a computer program which among other things computes huge binary prime numbers.  I am testing it on 16 digit numbers.  So here is my question.  So I generate 100 random odd numbers  (aka a 16 digit string of binary numbers that begin and end with one).  Then using the fact that 
$$
\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\log x}
$$
Then obviously a rough approximation of the number of primes I will generate find in this range with 100 random guess is 
$$
2 * 100\frac{\left(\frac{2^{16}}{\log{2^{16}}}-\frac{2^{15}-1}{\log(2^{15}-1)} \right)}{2^{16}-2^{15}+1}
$$
since it would be twice the number of primes in the range $[2^{15}-1,2^{16}]$ since I am only considering odd numbers.  However this gives me about ~38 primes and my code is generating consistently 16-25. So is my math wrong or is this approximation not good for this (relatively) small values of $\pi(x)$.

Comment: Doubling the formula is not correct, you aren’t counting anything twice or half as many times, the formula gives an approximation regardless of how you are counting...

Comment: A minor point: primes are primes no matter the base.  Just mentioning this because I wasn't sure why you mentioned the numbers were represented in binary.  You might be interested to know that it's not uncommon to represent big numbers on a computer in base $2^{16}$.

Comment: " twice the number of primes in the range" you think there are *even* primes in that range?

Comment: but there are no even primes in the range thus taking out the even ones would make there be more primes found in my program

Comment: edited for clarity

Comment: $x / \log x$ gives you an approximation of the number of primes in the interval $[2, x]$.  Why do you think the formula will change if you exclude even numbers?  The only even prime is $2$, so the actual count decreases by $1$, which doesn't change the approximation.

Comment: but since it is the number of primes this range since I am only considering odd number then when calculating the chance I multiply by 2

Comment: @tilper It looks like they are using it as an estimate of the probability of finding a prime, and they are conditioning it on the space of odd numbers.

Comment: @KyleMiller, I see now.  The way the post is written it sounds like OP is doubling the prime-counting formula $(x / \log x)$, but upon inspecting the formula (incorrectly labeled "an approximation of the number of primes"), it seems OP is actually calculating a probability.  Also,  the original version of the post had a formula that wasn't a probability, but rather, was the actual number of primes.  Perhaps the label didn't get updated with the formula.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the exact number helps, Mathematica can compute `PrimePi[2^16] - PrimePi[2^15 - 1]` to be $3030$.  Choosing one-hundred odd integers uniformly at random from $[2^{15},2^{16}]$, the expected number of primes among them is $20200/10923\approx 18.4931$.

Calculating the approximation with the prime number theorem, I get approximately $16.8315$.  The logarithms are supposed to be base-$e$: if I redo the calculation with base-$10$ logarithms, I get approximately $38.7559$.

Comment: So I did base teen instead of base e. dad gum thanks

Comment: the log symbol when we are talking cross discipline is somewhat ambiguous in fact when I initially did this calculation I assumed that it was $\log_2$ then in the middle I remember that for most "people"  the $\log_{10}$ however I forgot in my ramblings that for number theorists its $\log_e$ :)